# Ajax second call response contains first ajax response

Tags: php, ajax

I am having a very strange issue with nested AJAX calls
I create a simple AJAX call with php, I have two AJAX calls. The second call always contains json data from the second call plus data from first call.

Here my code:

**PHP**

```
<?php

...
if (isset($_REQUEST['ajax_action']) && !empty($_REQUEST['ajax_action'])) {
    $action = $_REQUEST['ajax_action'];

    switch ($action) {
        /**
         * Scheda
         */
        case 'Scheda_getSchedeBySerie':
            $idSerie = isset($_REQUEST["idSerie"]) ? $_REQUEST["idSerie"]: NULL;
            echo Scheda::getSchedeBySerie($idSerie);        
        /**
         * Serie
         */ 
        case 'Serie_getSeriesByUSer':
            $idDb = isset($_REQUEST["ID_DB"]) ? $_REQUEST["ID_DB"]: NULL;  
            $userName = isset($_REQUEST["userName"]) ? $_REQUEST["userName"]: NULL;
            //ob_start();
            echo Serie::getSeriesByUSer($idDb, $userName);
            break;
    }
}
?>
```

**AJAX first call**

```
var data = {
            ajax_action: 'Serie_getSeriesByUSer', 
            ID_DB: '<?php echo $ID_DB; ?>',
            userName: '<?php echo $username; ?>',
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
         type: "post",
         data: data ,
         dataType: 'html',   
         async: false,
         success: function (response) {
             alert(response);
                var list = $.parseJSON(response);
                var source = [];
                for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    var group = "<div>" + list[i].editore.trim() + "</div>";
                    var html = "<div>  " + list[i].collana.trim() + "</div>";
                    var title = list[i].idSerie.trim();

                    if(i == 0)
                        idSerieTo = list[i].idSerie.trim();

                    var r = {html: html, title: title, group: group };
                    source.push(r);
                }
                $('#ddlElencoCollaneCI').off('select');
                $("#ddlElencoCollaneCI").jqxDropDownList({ source: source});

                var item = $('#ddlElencoCollaneCI').jqxDropDownList('getItem', 0);
                    if (item != null) {
                        idSerieTo = item.label;
                        PopolaElencoLibri(idSerieTo);
                    }

                $('#ddlElencoCollaneCI').on('select', function (event) {
                    var args = event.args;
                    var item = $('#ddlElencoCollaneCI').jqxDropDownList('getItem', args.index);
                    if (item != null) {
                        idSerieTo = item.label; 
                        PopolaElencoLibri(idSerieTo);
                    }
                });
           },
```

**AJAX second call**

```
function PopolaElencoLibri(idSerie) {

        var data = {
            ajax_action: 'Scheda_getSchedeBySerie', 
            idSerie: idSerie,
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
         type: "post",
         data: data ,
         dataType: 'html', 
         async: false,       
         success: function (response) {

// response contain Scheda_getSchedeBySerie result AND Serie_getSeriesByUSer :(
                alert(response);
                var list = $.parseJSON(response);
                var source = [];
                for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    var group = "<div></div>";
                    var html = "<div>  " + list[i].numerodescr.trim() + "</div>";
                    var title = list[i].idScheda.trim();

                    //if(i == 0)
                    //  idSerieTo = list[i].idSerie.trim();

                    var r = {html: html, title: title, group: group };
                    source.push(r);
                }
                $("#ddlElencoLibriCI").jqxDropDownList({ source: source});
            }
        });  
    }
```

response data of the second ajax call contain Scheda_getSchedeBySerie result AND Serie_getSeriesByUSer.

I'll try ob_start(); and ob_end_clean(); but no data was returned.

Any idea? I'm new to php and AJAX.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should add `break` after each case statement.

```php
switch ($action) {
    /**
     * Scheda
     */
    case 'Scheda_getSchedeBySerie':
        $idSerie = isset($_REQUEST["idSerie"]) ? $_REQUEST["idSerie"]: NULL;
        echo Scheda::getSchedeBySerie($idSerie);        
        break;
    /**
     * Serie
     */ 
    case 'Serie_getSeriesByUSer':
        $idDb = isset($_REQUEST["ID_DB"]) ? $_REQUEST["ID_DB"]: NULL;  
        $userName = isset($_REQUEST["userName"]) ? $_REQUEST["userName"]: NULL;
        //ob_start();
        echo Serie::getSeriesByUSer($idDb, $userName);
        break;
}
```